# Getting correct Sum for total row DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have:
Dim Table:
Accounts: customer granularity level.

Fact Table:
PhoneCalls. calls to customers granularity level.

I need to create and see the number of calls made to a customer up until the customer made their first deposit.

I was able to do this on the customer level but on the Total level I get a weird result:

my measure:

```
ACC_Calls_2_FDP = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(PhoneCalls),
    PhoneCalls[disposition] = "ANSWERED", -- only calls that were answered
    PhoneCalls[calldate] <= MAX(Accounts[FDP_Date]), -- up until FDP date per customer
    USERELATIONSHIP(Accounts[AccountNo],PhoneCalls[AccountNo]) -- make the connection active
)
```

the results are:

[image]

On the total level i was expecting to see 14. not **536**
what is going on? what am i missing?

The data model:
Filter direction: Accounts filters PhoneCalls
Cardinality 1:*

Comment: provide sample data and expected output based on the data.

Comment: Start by figuring out what 536 means. Perhaps it is the total number of calls across all accounts in your dataset? It should give you context on what you are missing in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI doesn't sum up each of the row values as in Excel. Instead, for Grand total value they will still calculate it as a row itself with no filters on AccountNo on it.

In this case, the max value of FDP_Date in the whole table is taken in the measure. So for example, ACC 1 has max date of 3,  ACC 3 has the max of 10. The grand total calculation will use 10 as the max value and start countrows on whichever rows with FDP_Date < 10.

To fix this is tricky as I don't have any other information than this. However, I hope this explains you well of the "bug".